# Installing Steam on ubuntu 14.04 libc.so.6 error please help

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, steam

Hello everyone so I have been running Debian Linux for a while and decided to switch back over and dual boot with Ubuntu to play games again. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04

I installed Steam from the software center and it installed and I went to run it from the terminal by typing in `steam`

This is what I get  :

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

That is the error I receive. This is a fresh brand new install the only thing I have installed in steam if I could please get help with that it would be amazing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, search for an application called "software & updates".

Open this application.

Next, make sure **main, universe, restricted, and multiverse** are all enabled.

Now, before you try and go installing new software, you need to do all your system upgrades first:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot when finished. Then you can install steam:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 steam
```

Comment: That had worked greatly! I tried another persons method however I think if I had added the steam at the end it may of worked. I am not sure why having steam at the end made it work and with out it, it just failed.

Comment: good one. ;=)+1