# Steam not starting on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, steam

I'm trying to install Steam onto my computer in Ubuntu 16.04, but whenever I try to start steam I get this error message:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
```

libc.so.6

How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Steam on ubuntu 14.04 libc.so.6 error please help](http://askubuntu.com/questions/671160/installing-steam-on-ubuntu-14-04-libc-so-6-error-please-help)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

1. `find | grep libc.so.6`
2. Copy/Remember the path shown by the command's output
3. Create a link to the /lib folder using `sudo ln -s <your-libc-path-here> /lib/libc.so.6`

Guessing this should solve it.

Comment: They need the i386 version

Comment: @mchid I assumed that it must be present but messed up due to some multiarch thing or hardcoded Steam code.